# Number of dynos vs the type (performance) of dynos (2X option)

Tags: heroku

Would it make more sense to have 2 2X dynos running, or 4 1X dynos? Technically this would be about the same sum total compute power, and also about the same price, but as I'm new to this type of setup, I don't know what other considerations there might be, and would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, 2X dynos have more memory. If your app is built such that you need more memory than 1X dynos can supply, it seems like 2X are the answer. As for my personal preference, I like the resolution that 1X dynos offer (I can have 3 of them, for example, but can't have 1.5 2X dynos), so unless I need to I stick with 1X dynos.